# Does blender have a simple particle system method for smoke, etc?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

I know about blenders mantaflow smoke simulation, but I'm looking for a more simpler way to do it like how Unity 3D's particle system works, or Lightwaves.

Its basically just particles with sprites attached to them, with no actual smoke calculations. I'm very new to blenders particle system in general, so if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. All the info I can find about doing smoke in blender points to the mantaflow system.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hx8m9w4YyNo

This might hold the answers you seek

Comment: There are many ways to fake smoke without doing a smoke simulation.  https://youtu.be/tL0G5oOjdtk is one of the better youtube tutorials on how to do it with a particle system.  A second approach is to use textures as in this tutorial: https://youtu.be/okcQkF0uN-M  There's also the sprite 'billboard' approach: https://youtu.be/hx8m9w4YyNo as mentioned by @NascentSpace